# Speed up pandas dataframe lookup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with zip codes, city, state and country of ~ 600,000 locations. Let's call it **my_df**

I'd like to look up the corresponding ***longitude*** and ***latitude*** for each of these locations. Thankfully, there is a database for [this](http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us). Let's call this dataframe **zipdb**.

`zipdb` has, among others, columns for zip codes, city, state and country.
So, I'd like to look up all of the locations (zip, city, state and country) in `zipdb`.

```
def zipdb_lookup(zipcode, city, state, country):

   countries_mapping = { "UNITED STATES":"US"
                     , "CANADA":"CA"
                     , "KOREA REP OF":"KR"
                     , "ITALY":"IT"
                     , "AUSTRALIA":"AU"
                     , "CHILE":"CL"
                     , "UNITED KINGDOM":"GB"
                     , "BERMUDA":"BM"
    }

    try:
        slc = zipdb[ (zipdb.Zipcode == str(zipcode)) &
                     (zipdb.City == str(city).upper()) &
                     (zipdb.State == str(state).upper()) &
                     (zipdb.Country == countries_mapping[country].upper()) ]

        if slc.shape[0] == 1:
            return np.array(slc["Lat"])[0], np.array(slc["Long"])[0]
        else:
            return None
    except:
         return None
```

I have tried pandas' `.apply` as well as a `for` loop to do this.
Both are very slow. I recognize there are a large number of rows, but I can't help but think something faster must be possible.

---

```
zipdb = pandas.read_csv("free-zipcode-database.csv") #linked to above
```

Note: I've also performed this transformation on `zibdb`:

```
zipdb["Zipcode"] = zipdb["Zipcode"].astype(str)
```

---

**Function Call:**

```
#Defined a wrapper function:
def lookup(row):
    """

    :param row:
    :return:
    """

    lnglat = zipdb_lookup(
                  zipcode = my_df["organization_zip"][row]
                , city    = my_df["organization_city"][row]
                , state   = my_df["organization_state"][row]
                , country = my_df["organization_country"][row]
    )

    return lnglat

lnglat = list()
for l in range(0, my_df.shape[0]):
    # if l % 5000 == 0: print(round((float(l) / my_df.shape[0])*100, 2), "%")
    lnglat.append(lookup(row = l))
```

---

Sample Data from `my_df`:

```
       organization_zip organization_city organization_state  organization_country
0                 60208          EVANSTON                 IL   United Sates
1                 77555         GALVESTON                 TX   United Sates
2                 23284          RICHMOND                 VA   United Sates
3                 53233         MILWAUKEE                 WI   United Sates
4                 10036          NEW YORK                 NY   United Sates
5                 33620             TAMPA                 FL   United Sates
6                 10029          NEW YORK                 NY   United Sates
7                 97201          PORTLAND                 OR   United Sates
8                 97201          PORTLAND                 OR   United Sates
9                 53715           MADISON                 WI   United Sates
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Did you try using `join` or `merge` to join your DataFrame with the zipdb?

Comment: @ayhan I've updated the question.

Comment: @Brenbarn...that is actually a very good idea. I'll try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`merge()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) will be a lot faster than calling a function on every row. Make sure the field types match and strings are stripped:

```
# prepare your dataframe
data['organization_zip'] = data.organization_zip.astype(str)
data['organization_city'] = data.organization_city.apply(lambda v: v.strip())
# get the zips database
zips = pd.read_csv('/path/to/free-zipcode-database.csv')
zips['Zipcode'] = zips.Zipcode.astype(str)
# left join
# -- prepare common join columns
zips.rename(columns=dict(Zipcode='organization_zip',
                         City='organization_city'), 
            inplace=True)  
# specify join columns along with zips' columns to copy
cols = ['organization_zip', 'organization_city', 'Lat', 'Long']
data.merge(zips[cols], how='left')
=>
```

[image: result]

Note you may need to extend the merge columns and/or add more columns to copy from the zips dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'd also like to bring the `long`, `lat` columns along for the ride. This may be easy to do now? I haven't had a chance to try yet.

Comment: `Long`, `Lat` were copied already but not visible in the screenshot. Changed to a perhaps more straight forward approach using common column names for the merge keys.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I come from R...so it's strange for me to see methods like `join` and `merge` work so well (joke, kind of. haha). Thanks again.